# Generate random number between 1 and 10 with the exception of a single number in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to generate a random number between 1 and 10 using for example `randi([1,10])` but I would like to exclude a single number, say 7 - this number would always change and be specified in a variable called `b`.

Is that possible to do somehow?

Comment: Just loop on the `Randi([1,10])` until the result is not equal `b`.

Comment: yes but this would happen within a program and I'm not there to supervise this. I'm looking for some argument that omits b.

Comment: @user1723765 Looping and testing can be automated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html). For instance, to generate a number between 1 and 10, excluding 7, do the following:

```
b = 7;
x = randsample(setdiff(1:10, b), 1);
```

Here [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) is used to exclude the value of `b` from the vector `1:10`.

If you don't have the Statistics Toolbox installed, you won't be able to use `randsample`, so use [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html):

```
v = setdiff(1:10, b);
x = v(ceil(numel(v) * rand));
```

Comment: For the second solution one can use `x=v(randi(numel(v)));`

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Yes, you're right. But also keep in mind that there's no `randi` in older versions of MATLAB.

Comment: Well, `randi` appeared in R2008b and I think the number of people who do not have statistics toolbox are way larger than people who have it on a version more than 5 years old.

Answer (score 5):

For those without the statistics toolbox:

```
b = 7;
pop = 1:10;
pop(b) = [];
```

then

```
pop(randperm(9,1))
```

or for `n` random integers from the population:

```
pop(randi(numel(pop), 1, n))
```

Comment: `randperm` is okay if you don't want repetitions.

Comment: @glglgl it's not really necessary for the question but I changed it to `numel(pop)` instead so now the population can even be a grid of numbers if desired.

Answer (score 1):

As @EitanT mentioned, you can use `randsample` to do so, but I think that doing so in a simpler manner should do for you:

```
>> b = 7;
>> randsample([1:b-1,b+1:10],1)
```

This simply samples a random value from the array `[1:b-1,b+1:10]` which would here be

```
1     2     3     4     5     6     8     9    10
```

Or similarly, if the `randsample' function is unavailable as @EitanT had mentioned,

```
v = [1:b-1,b+1:10];
x = v(ceil(numel(v) * rand));
```

Comment: What if b=1 or b=10?